# Unit test run works within Eclipse but not from console

Tags: python, eclipse, unit-testing

The organisiation of my project looks like the following:

- TopFolder

  - SomeProject

    - SomeClass.py
  - SomeProject_UnitTests

    - SomeTest.py

SomeClass.py:

```
class SomeClass:

    def add( self, x, y ):
        return x + y
```

SomeTest.py:

```
import unittest
from SomeProject.SomeClass import SomeClass

class SomeTest( unittest.TestCase ):
    
    def test_sumShouldAlwaysReturnRightValue(self):
        x = 5
        y = 10
        obj = SomeClass()
        
        result = obj.add(x, y)
        
        expectedResult = 15
        self.assertEqual( expectedResult, result )
```

If I run the unit tests using Eclipse (open file SomeClassTest.py and click run selecting "Python unit test") it works fine.
In order to run all unit tests of the whole SomeProject_UnitTests folder at once, I tried to run the follwing command at the MINGW64 console:

```
python -m unittest discover -p '*Test.py'
```

It fails with the following error:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: someTest (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: someTest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[Python_Path]\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "[Python_Path]\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "[Path_To_SomeProject_UnitTests]\SomeTest.py", line 8, in <module>
    from MVxRegressionTester.SomeClass import SomeClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SomeProject'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I also tried an to add an init file to the folder SomeProject_UnitTests with an entry that appends the folder SomeProject to the sys path. It did not help neither.

Why is the Eclipse run recognizing the source project, but the execution inside the console fails to integrate it?

Comment: I don't know if Eclipse supplies these implicitly, but your directory hierarchy is missing the `__init__.py` modules that turn the directories in to Python packages.

Comment: @chepner I added an __init__.py file to every folder (TopFolder, SomeProject and SomeProject_UnitTests). Sadly the result stays the same.